# How to use ROW_COUNT() with Rails delete_all

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way in Rails to access mysql information function ROW_COUNT() when using Rails delete_all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get from delete_all or destroy_all should be an array of all the objects that were deleted, so if you have 2 Users:

```
User.delete_all.size # => 2
```